# Is this system of responsive images a good practice? Using html5 data?

Tags: jquery, image, html, responsive-design

I have searched and tried several techniques for responsive/adaptive images but I have found that most of them interfere with the html5 cache manifest.

I would like feedback on whether this method is a good practice (note: it does delay downloading of images until the scripts are running but prevents double downloads of image resources)

typical html:

```
<img data-name="001.jpg">
<img data-name="002.jpg">
<img data-name="003.jpg">
```

the javascript:

```
var fullTest=$(window).width();
if ((fullTest < 1025) && (fullTest > 600) ){
    var imageFolder = 'photos/medium/';
    console.log('medium images');
} else if (fullTest > 1024) {
    var imageFolder = 'photos/large/';
    console.log('large images');
} else {
    var imageFolder = 'photos/';
    console.log('small images');
}

$('img').each(function () {
    imageName = $(this).data('name');
    if (imageName){
       $(this).attr('src', imageFolder + imageName);
       console.log(imageName+"was changed");
    } else { 
        console.log($(this).attr('src')+" was not changed");
    }
});
```

Comment: Similar, but different approach - http://filamentgroup.com/lab/responsive_images_experimenting_with_context_aware_image_sizing/

Comment: yup. that's the one that broke my cache manifest file. It stores the images in the root folder of the site, but my system reads through all folders from the html file where it is called, and it doesn't 'remember' the same set of files.